# Executing function after python test suite finished execution

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm using python unittest frame work for do some testing.

```
class AbstractTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):


  def tearDown(self):
    # Close!
    self.transport.close()

  def testVoid(self):
    self.client.testVoid()

  def testString(self):
    global test_basetypes_fails
    try:
      self.assertEqual(self.client.testString('Python' * 20), 'Python' * 20)
    except AssertionError, e:
      test_basetypes_fails = True
      print test_basetypes_fails
      raise AssertionError( e.args )
    try:
      self.assertEqual(self.client.testString(''), '')
    except AssertionError, e:
      test_basetypes_fails = True
      raise AssertionError( e.args )

  def testByte(self):
    global test_basetypes_fails
    try:
      self.assertEqual(self.client.testByte(63), 63)
    except AssertionError, e:
      test_basetypes_fails = True
      raise AssertionError( e.args )
    try:
      self.assertEqual(self.client.testByte(-127), -127)
    except AssertionError, e:
      test_basetypes_fails = True
      raise AssertionError( e.args )

  @classmethod
  def tearDownClass(cls):
    #sys.exit(1)
```

When I execute my test I am getting following result.

```
..................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 18 tests in 2.715s

OK
```

I need to execute a piece of program after this finishes execution. How can I do that? When I add code to class level tear down it executes it after following part of output is made.

```
..................
```

Comment: Do you need this to run after *all* tests have executed, all tests meaning tests being possibly distributed over several TestCase-classes and/or modules?

Comment: I added my code above, tests are in a single class

Answer (score 2):

You need to write your own testrunner, so that you can return with an exit-code depending on the result of the suite.

All you need to do is explained in the unittest-module documentation. Use a TestLoader to load your suite, and a TextTestRunner to run it. Then depending on the result of the suite, call sys.exit with your appropriate exit-code.